# Comma-seperated model binding

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-binding

After reading https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Binding on string array with comma-seperated attribute is a must for us. However, this article only describes how to do this on the method, with simple types. I would prefer to put a attribute on the property on some complex model.

Is this possible?

I can't get it to work otherwise then on the method.

---after edit---

I would like to get this

```
public class GetCatalogVehiclesRequest
{
    [commaseparated]
    public string[] Sorting { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

instead of (on controller):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([commaseperated]GetCatalogVehiclesRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken){...}
```

So on my model instead of an attribute on the parameter.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: @Amy i've changed it. hopefully it is now clear

Comment: Yes, that is clearer.  As I suspected, I did misunderstand, so I'm deleting my first comment.  That said, I don't know the answer, or whether that is possible.

Comment: We should tag your question with the appropriate technologies.  I surmise based on the link in the question that you are using Web API on ASP.Net Core?  If so, adding those tags will help get your question some additional visibility.

Comment: What you would need to do is create a custom model binder for that type